# Digitalized version of "Cours de topologie algébrique professé en captivité"

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ho.history-overview

It  is  historically  known  that  Jean Leray gave  a course  on algebraic topology while  captive  in the Officer's detention camp XVI  in  Edelbach, Austria during WW2. (References  to this  topic  include  an  article  by Sigmund, Michor  and Sigmund in  the  mathematical  Intelligencer,  27/2 (2005), 41-50.)

Is  there a  digitalized  copy  of  the course  material  somewhere?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The course has been published in the [Journal de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_de_Math%C3%A9matiques_Pures_et_Appliqu%C3%A9es), volume 24 (1945), and can be found here: [first part](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k97042399/f101.image) and [second part](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k97042399/f175.image) and [third part](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k97042399/f207.image).

A quote from Leray's [obituary:](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1515623)

> The prisoners in the camp were mostly educated men, career or reserve
>   officers, many of them still students. As in several other camps, a
>   "university" was created and Leray became its rector. Classes were
>   taught, exams were given, and degrees granted, with some degree of
>   recognition by French authorities of the time. As for research, to
>   fight the feeling that he might be losing the best productive years of
>   his life, Leray wanted to resume his work. But he was confronted with
>   a dilemma. If he continued working in fluid mechanics, he might be
>   forced to collaborate with the German war effort. Instead, he decided
>   to pursue some ideas in algebraic topology that he had foreseen during
>   his collaboration with Schauder.

[image]
pages 95-167
[image]
pages 169-199
[image]
pages 201-248